# Realization of "IsProcessorFeaturePresent" on C++

Tags: c++, windows

Help please remake a small piece of code from C# to C++

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (ProcessorFeature feature in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(ProcessorFeature)))
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(feature.ToString() + "\t: " + IsProcessorFeaturePresent(feature));
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Kernel32")]
    static extern bool IsProcessorFeaturePresent(ProcessorFeature processorFeature);

    enum ProcessorFeature : uint
    {
        PF_FLOATING_POINT_PRECISION_ERRATA = 0,
        PF_FLOATING_POINT_EMULATED = 1,
        PF_COMPARE_EXCHANGE_DOUBLE = 2,
        PF_MMX_INSTRUCTIONS_AVAILABLE = 3,
        PF_PPC_MOVEMEM_64BIT_OK = 4,
        PF_ALPHA_BYTE_INSTRUCTIONS = 5,
        PF_XMMI_INSTRUCTIONS_AVAILABLE = 6,
        PF_3DNOW_INSTRUCTIONS_AVAILABLE = 7,
        PF_RDTSC_INSTRUCTION_AVAILABLE = 8,
        PF_PAE_ENABLED = 9,
        PF_XMMI64_INSTRUCTIONS_AVAILABLE = 10,
        PF_SSE_DAZ_MODE_AVAILABLE = 11,
        PF_NX_ENABLED = 12,
        PF_SSE3_INSTRUCTIONS_AVAILABLE = 13,
        PF_COMPARE_EXCHANGE128 = 14,
        PF_COMPARE64_EXCHANGE128 = 15,
        PF_CHANNELS_ENABLED = 16,
        PF_XSAVE_ENABLED = 17,
        PF_SECOND_LEVEL_ADDRESS_TRANSLATION = 20,
        PF_VIRT_FIRMWARE_ENABLED = 21,
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create an enumeration, but the compiler writes "Need an identifier". 
The compiler writes that there is already a definition in "winnt.h"

```
#define PF_FLOATING_POINT_PRECISION_ERRATA   0
```

I connected the library as stated in [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724482(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
#include <winnt.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "Kernel32.lib")
```

I don't even know how "foreach" is implemented on C++.

Comment: Don't try to follow it so strictly, instead of the enum just use a `for` loop from 0 to 21...

Comment: And you thought this would be interesting for other language users, to, so you spammed the C# and C tags, too? Why not Brainfuck and Algol?

Comment: You're not going to be able to `foreach` an `enum` in C++, so a regular `for` loop as Gusman suggests, or from PF_FLOATING_POINT_PRECISION_ERRATA to PF_VIRT_FIRMWARE_ENABLED

Comment: @PhilM Can  you give me a small example? I need the output, written "false" or "true", as in the example.

Comment: `DWORD f = PF_RDTSCP_INSTRUCTION_AVAILABLE;
 do 
 {
  if (IsProcessorFeaturePresent(f))
  {
   DbgPrint("%02u\n", f);
  }
 } while (f--);`

Comment: I could give an example of a for loop, but that's about it; I'm not familiar with querying process features

Comment: If you actually put that mess into a C++ compiler you got a lot more argument from the compiler than "Need an identifier"...You haven't even provided enough information so that somebody could write the code for you if they wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

Because C++ doesn't have reflection, accessing names of an enumeration appears difficult.  But the stringizing operator fits very nicely:

```
#define VAL_AND_NAME(x) { x, #x }
struct { int val; const char* name; } const features[] = {
    VAL_AND_NAME(PF_FLOATING_POINT_PRECISION_ERRATA),
    VAL_AND_NAME(PF_FLOATING_POINT_EMULATED),
    VAL_AND_NAME(PF_COMPARE_EXCHANGE_DOUBLE),
    VAL_AND_NAME(PF_MMX_INSTRUCTIONS_AVAILABLE),
    VAL_AND_NAME(PF_PPC_MOVEMEM_64BIT_OK),
    VAL_AND_NAME(PF_ALPHA_BYTE_INSTRUCTIONS),
    VAL_AND_NAME(PF_XMMI_INSTRUCTIONS_AVAILABLE),
    VAL_AND_NAME(PF_3DNOW_INSTRUCTIONS_AVAILABLE),
    VAL_AND_NAME(PF_RDTSC_INSTRUCTION_AVAILABLE),
    VAL_AND_NAME(PF_PAE_ENABLED),
    VAL_AND_NAME(PF_XMMI64_INSTRUCTIONS_AVAILABLE),
    VAL_AND_NAME(PF_SSE_DAZ_MODE_AVAILABLE),
    VAL_AND_NAME(PF_NX_ENABLED),
    VAL_AND_NAME(PF_SSE3_INSTRUCTIONS_AVAILABLE),
    VAL_AND_NAME(PF_COMPARE_EXCHANGE128),
    VAL_AND_NAME(PF_COMPARE64_EXCHANGE128),
    VAL_AND_NAME(PF_CHANNELS_ENABLED),
    VAL_AND_NAME(PF_XSAVE_ENABLED),
    VAL_AND_NAME(PF_SECOND_LEVEL_ADDRESS_TRANSLATION),
    VAL_AND_NAME(PF_VIRT_FIRMWARE_ENABLED),
};
```

Now that you have an array of (value, name) pairs, you simply loop through.  The ranged-for syntax works nicely:

```
char buffer[1000];
for( auto f : features ) {
    wsprintfA(buffer, "%40s : %s\n",
                      f.name, IsProcessorFeaturePresent(f.val)? "true": "false");
    // write buffer to standard output or wherever you like
}
```

Comment: NB: Using `wsprintf` because a tiny tool like this doesn't need the C++ runtime library if compiled with `/GS-`.  Link with `/NODEFAULTLIB`, and the executable size drops below 4kB and depends only on the DLLs shipped by every Windows version since 32-bits were a shiny new feature of the 80386.

Comment: Thanks for the example, but it does not work for me, does not print anything, I do not even know why, there are no errors.

Comment: @PavelFedorov: Did you put printing code where the comment indicates?

Comment: Yes, I did as you wrote, but still an empty window gives me, besides `wsprintf`

Comment: This is my complete file, which certainly prints output when I compile and run it: https://gist.github.com/BenVoigt/d273f9c3309395e4ade4d22adb29c170

Comment: It works, but I did not have to remove two the "linker", I don't even know why they do not work, Although I have msvs15